# How to fetch next 3 items from an object using for loop with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm fetching some data from a site and storing it into a variable. Then I'm running a for loop to return 3 properties from that object every time I click a button, and that part is working flawlessly.

Except, it's returning the exact same data with every button click. I'm not sure how to start the for loop from a specific object.

```
data: {
    fetched_list: [],   // the object containing the data fetched when called
    list: [],          // an empty list that will contain future pushed object
    list_key: '0'     // the last loop index
},

requestInformation(){
  const temp = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    temp.push(this.fetched_list[i]);
  }
  this.list = this.list.concat(temp); // here we push the fetched data to the list
}
```

At this point I'm just not sure how to start the for loop at the next 3 objects every time I click a button.

I was trying to save the last **i** number to the list_key but I'm not sure how to use it to fetch the next 3 properties.

I've recreated the exact issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/auq7wzuc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that need changing.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/auq7wzuc/6/

Basically, the following line:

```
this.recipe.list_key = this.recipe.list_key++;
```

Will never increment the value-- it will always be zero. We want to increment by 3, so we should use:

```
this.recipe.list_key += 3;
```

Also, we need to change the terms of the for loop, so instead of stopping at 3, it stops at 3 more than the start.

Comment: Yes, that makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Noticed a mistake in the way you increment `this.recipe.list_key` and your comparison of `i < 3` in the `for` loop. I've modified it to make it work. Take a look at the code below. Hope this is what you needed.

I have also taken the liberty of changing `list_key` initial value from char '0' to int 0. (To handle the JavaScript concatenation vs addition issue)

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        recipe: {
            fetched_list: [],
        list: [],
            list_key: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
    requestInformation(){
      const temp = [];
      console.log(this.recipe.list_key);
      var end = this.recipe.list_key + 3;
      for (let i = this.recipe.list_key; i < end ; i++){
        temp.push(this.recipe.fetched_list[i]);
      }
      this.recipe.list_key += 3;
      this.recipe.list = this.recipe.list.concat(temp);
    }
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=story').then(({data}) => this.recipe.fetched_list = data.hits);  
    }
});
```

Doubts/clarifications welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
data: {
    recipe: {
        fetched_list: [],
    list: [],
        list_key: 0
    }
},
methods: {
 requestInformation() {
  this.recipe.list = this.recipe.fetched_list
    .slice(0, this.recipe.list_key += 2)
    .map(item => item);
 }
}
```